# Why can't I override onAttachFragment?

Tags: android, fragment, android-support-library

I have a class extending from android.support.v4.app.Fragment. The documentation [android.support.v4.app.Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) shows that there is a method called `onAttachFragment(Fragment childFragment)`, but I can't override it in Android Studio. It's like it doesn't exist. Is there a reason for this, or is this an error in documentation? `android.app.Fragment` non-support version says it has been added in API level 24. That shouldn't matter though should it? Since I am using the support version which has the same class.

Edit:
Here are my dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':core-3.2.1')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8+'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:0.7.0@aar'
}
```

Comment: Can you include your `build.gradle` file? Specifically the dependencies section

Comment: I have added my dependencies.

Comment: maybe it is a syntax thing? can also add your class & where you are trying to override this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `23.4.0` release of the Support Library. Only the `24.X` (i.e., `24.1.1`) versions of the Support Library will contain the equivalent APIs added in API 24.

You'll need to upgrade your version of the Support Library to use the new APIs.

Comment: Note that as per the [Google Play services 9.0.1 release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_2016_-_v90), there is an incompatibility when using Google Play services < 9.0.1 and `24.0.0` or higher of the Support Library, so you might need to upgrade your Google Play services dependency as well (and please, please switch to [split dependencies](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split) - they're much, much smaller)

Comment: Thanks! I thought when I updated my SDK, it would edit the gradle files, but didn't. I'm guessing it might when I use Android Studio's SDK manager, but I always close that and open the original one.

Comment: Android Studio doesn't update your dependencies for you as it certainly might change the behavior or break things before you're ready, but you will get a warning in your `build.gradle` that a newer version is available after you've updated through the SDK Manager.